# Upgraded to geth 1.5.0: Bad block #383792

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, nodes, bug, upgrading

Recent Hardfork #4 Spurious Dragon has forced me to upgrade the geth node to last version.

After upgrading geth node to version 1.5.0 and reseting all blockchain data, to start from scratch, I got the following fatal error using testnet:

```
E1121 16:21:27.722211 core/blockchain.go:1212] Bad block #383792 (0x114aa8935ec9c308bdddd52030f096801be916e69b1b5db49aa87112472775eb)
E1121 16:21:27.722249 core/blockchain.go:1213]     gas used error (1554920 / 3141592)
```

This is the command line used to lauch geth:

```
./geth --rpc --testnet
```

Any ideas how to fix it? Is that a bug on 1.5.0 version? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I've recently updated my testnet node to 1.5.0-dev (using the nightly builds repo for Ubuntu 14.04) and haven't experienced this behaviour. I've tried it both with the pre-existing blockchain database, and after `removedb`.

However, I always run `geth` with fast-sync enabled, like this:

```
nice geth --testnet --fast console 2>> ~/var/log/geth/`today`-`now`.log
```

Could you try resetting your DB again and running with `--fast`? This would narrow the scope.

Other than that: how are you building/installing?

Comment: Just by getting binaries from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/download/v1.5.0/geth-linux-amd64-1.5.0-c3c58eb6.tar.gz

Comment: I have removed again my testnet blockchain data and started from scratch... same error.